# No module named 'pm4py.objects.petri' in pm4py

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using thePython open source [pm4py](https://github.com/pm4py), and following the blog: [Process Mining with Python tutorial: A healthcare application — Part 2](https://medium.com/@c3_62722/process-mining-with-python-tutorial-a-healthcare-application-part-2-4cf57053421f). When I ran

```
from pm4py.objects.conversion.log import converter as log_converter
from pm4py.algo.discovery.alpha import algorithm as alpha_miner
log = log_converter.apply(eventlog)
net, initial_marking, final_marking = alpha_miner.apply(log)
```

no problem at all.

But when I import the following visualization module

```
from pm4py.visualization.petrinet import visualizer as pn_visualizer
```

or try other module:

```
from pm4py.objects.petri import performance_map
```

it showed

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pm4py.visualization.petrinet'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pm4py.objects.petri'
```

I checked the documentation and the [classes](https://pm4py-source.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pm4py.visualization.petrinet.html#module-pm4py.visualization.petrinet.visualizer) do exist in the library, so they are not deprecated.

I googled but failed to find anyone to mention the bug. I also tried different python version 3.8, 3.9 and, even

```
pip install "pm4py==<early version>"
```

still doesn't work. Did anyone else have same issue? Thanks

Comment: So this message is when you're running the script or intellisense?

Comment: @BrendanOtherwhyz it happened when I ran the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hunted through the github for the name of these packages. Looks like the tutorial has them wrong or is using an older version perhaps?

They should be:

```
from pm4py.objects.conversion.log import converter as log_converter
from pm4py.algo.discovery.alpha import algorithm as alpha_miner
from pm4py.visualization.petri_net import visualizer as pn_visualizer
from pm4py.visualization.petri_net.util import performance_map
```

Comment: Awesome! Now they all work! I think the documentations are needed to be updated!

Comment: how did you find them? check the source code?

Comment: I just searched for them on the github page

Comment: You should raise an issue about that, they probably don't realise